# Why bother using mysql_real_escape_string() since $_POST addes slashes before a quote automatically?

Tags: php, post, escaping, quotes, mysql-real-escape-string

In PHP, $_POST add slashes before a quotation mark automatically, so why bother applying mysql_real_escape_string()? For example, when I input `'rrr` in an input field, and I get `\'rrr` when I echo it.

Comment: When I apply mysql_real_escape_string(), I get \\\'e when I echo the result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because that only happens if MacigQuotes is enabled in your php configuration, which, as far as I know, is fairly uncommon nowadays. Also, mysql_real_escape_string also escapes other MySQL related characters.

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php for more information on magic quotes.

As you can see, there already is a deprecation warning for this directive, so you should check your server configuration anyway^^

Edit: To disable magic quotes, search in your xampp folder for the php.ini, and add, or change if present, the following directives:

```
; Magic quotes
;

; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Comment: How can I disable MagicQuotes in my PHP configuration? I am using xampp.

Comment: @Steven - Open up "c:\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini", find the line reading "magic_quotes_gpc = On", change "On" to "Off", save, and restart Apache via the XAMPP control panel.

Answer (score 6):

1. mysql_real_escape_string escapes more than just single-quotes, because there are other chars that can cause injection issues.
2. PHP only adds slashes to POSTed input if magic_quotes is enabled, which is considered bad practice (because it leads to laziness and not using things like real_escape_string!)

Answer (score 3):

Magic quotes [was deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0](http://us.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) and is obsolete as of PHP 6.0.

Edit:  So the auto slashes can't be relied on because they are deprecated by most PHP installations, and soon will not work at all.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Comment: Of course it is, but imho it should've been a comment to either mine or Ciaran's answer, as we both mention magic_quotes already.

Comment: How can I disable MagicQuotes in my PHP configuration? I am using xampp.